# print or save to file for Landscape RDLC report its not working

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, report, rdlc

I'm using the RDLC Report Designer in VS2010

my report size is (11.694,8.269) in inch 
A4  landscape

when I want print report or save it as a pdf file Landscape report its not working

for Portrait report print/save to file  working fine, but unfortunately for Landscape report its not working

can anyone help me ?

any ideas, comments from your side would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: what issue you are facing while Landscape report ??

Answer (score 0):

You must set the exact value for PageWidth and PageHeight.
I always use 29.7cm and 21cm; it seems that the correct values in inches are 11in and 8.5in.

Source: [Walkthrough: Printing a Local Report without Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx)